# Comparing values between two data frames to produce a concatenated output file

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, dfA and dfB.

dfA:

```
ID <- c('ID1','ID2','ID3','ID4')
lowval <- c(12,13,20,40)
upval <- c(14,15,22,42)
cr <- c("item1","item2","item3","item4")
dfA <- data.frame(ID,lowval,upval,cr)

>dfA
   ID lowval upval    cr
1 ID1     12    14 item1
2 ID2     13    15 item2
3 ID3     20    22 item3
4 ID4     40    42 item4
```

dfB:

```
match <- c('30','30','30','30')
pos <- c(3,13,18,41)
desc <- c("heavy","light","blue","black")
dfB <- data.frame(match,pos,desc)

>dfB
  match pos  desc
1    30   3 heavy
2    30  13 light
3    30  18  blue
4    30  41 black
```

I want to run through each row to ask if the dfB$pos lies between dfA$lowval and dfB$upval, and if so, print the whole row from dfA and dfB into an output file.

The desired output file in this case would look like this:

```
   ID lowval upval    cr match pos  desc
  ID1     12    14 item1    30  13 light
  ID4     40    42 item4    30  41 black
```

I have have tried creating a function:

```
f <- function(x, y, output) {
lowervalue = x[2]
uppervalue = x[3]
position = y[2]
if(position>=lowervalue & position<=uppervalue){
print(paste(x,y,sep="\t"))
cat(paste(x,y, sep="\t"), file= output, append = T, fill = T)
}
}
apply(dfA, dfB, f, output = 'outputfile.txt')
```

However I received the following error:

```
Error in ds[-MARGIN] : invalid subscript type 'list'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(left) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Could someone suggest a solution to creating this output file?  I'm very stuck.

Comment: take a look into `data.table::foverlaps`. Or search for it on this site. There are plenty of examples.

Comment: You're getting the error because you're passing all of `dfB` to `apply`'s `MARGIN` argument, which can only take values of `1` or `2`, which tell it to run over rows or columns, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
merge(dfA, dfB)[c(sapply(dfB$pos, function(x) apply(dfA[2:3], 1, function(y) 
y[1] <= x & y[2] >= x))),]

    ID lowval upval    cr match pos  desc
5  ID1     12    14 item1    30  13 light
6  ID2     13    15 item2    30  13 light
16 ID4     40    42 item4    30  41 black
```

Comment: This worked with my main dataframes, and seems the easiest solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1: [`outer()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/outer.html)

```
f <- 'output.txt';
write(capture.output(print(with(as.data.frame(which(outer(dfB$pos,dfA$lowval,`>=`) & outer(dfB$pos,dfA$upval,`<=`),arr.ind=T)),cbind(dfA[col,],dfB[row,])),row.names=F)),f);
cat(readLines(f),sep='\n');
##   ID lowval upval    cr match pos  desc
##  ID1     12    14 item1    30  13 light
##  ID2     13    15 item2    30  13 light
##  ID4     40    42 item4    30  41 black
```

In your question, you don't have `ID2` in your expected output, but based on inclusive comparison (e.g. `>=` vs. `>`) 13 is between 13 and 15, so it qualifies as a match.

## Solution 2: [`lapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)

```
f <- 'output.txt';
write(capture.output(print(do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(nrow(dfA)),function(ai) { res <- dfB$pos>=dfA$lowval[ai] & dfB$pos<=dfA$upval[ai]; if (any(res)) cbind(dfA[ai,],dfB[res,]); })),row.names=F)),f);
cat(readLines(f),sep='\n');
##   ID lowval upval    cr match pos  desc
##  ID1     12    14 item1    30  13 light
##  ID2     13    15 item2    30  13 light
##  ID4     40    42 item4    30  41 black
```